# How to pass data from Trigger to a view model in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I created this simple trigger:

```
public class SelectedChangedTrigger : TriggerAction<ListView>
    {

        protected override void Invoke(ListView sender)
        {
            var selectedItem = sender.SelectedItem as Item;

        }
    }
```

in XAML:

```
        <ListView.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger Event="ItemSelected">
                <triggers:SelectedChangedTrigger/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ListView.Triggers>
```

So I want to bind a `string` property in the view model to the `selectedItem.Title`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would highly recommend that, if you need to update view-model on `ItemSelected` event, then, use an [`EventToCommandBehaviour` to wire up the view's event with viewmodel's command](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/). Triggers should only be used for view based manipulation(s) like updating style, control state etc.

But if you still want to be able to use the trigger, I guess you can achieve that by using `BindingContext` and appropriate casting.

```
public class SelectedChangedTrigger : TriggerAction<ListView>
{

    protected override void Invoke(ListView sender)
    {
        var selectedItem = sender.SelectedItem as Item;

        var viewModel = selectedItem?.BindingContext as ViewModelType;
        viewModel.PerformAction(); //<-- your view-model's method or property to update/invoke 
    }
}
```